# Which is faster read(), or readline() or readlines() with respect file io in julia?

Tags: file-io, julia

Please correct me, if I were wrong:

`read` is efficient, as I assume:

a) `read` fetches whole file content to memory in one go, similar to python.

b) `readline` and `readlines` brings one line at a time to memory.

Comment: Yes. However using `readline` repeatedly (or `eachline` if you want a non-allocating iterator) might be preferred e.g. if your file is really large and does not fit into memory. Of course then you can also read file in chunks using `read`, but `readline` gives you a more structured data. Also `readlines` brings all lines into memory at once (as opposed to `eachline`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to expand on the comment here is some example benchmark (to additionally show you how you can perform such tests yourself).

First create some random test data:

```
open("testdata.txt", "w") do f
    for i in 1:10^6
        println(f, "a"^100)
    end
end
```

We will want to read in the data in four ways (and calculate the aggregate length of lines):

```
f1() = sum(length(l) for l in readlines("testdata.txt"))

f2() = sum(length(l) for l in eachline("testdata.txt"))

function f3()
    s = 0
    open("testdata.txt") do f
        while !eof(f)
            s += length(readline(f))
        end
    end
    s
end

function f4()
    s = 0
    for c in read("testdata.txt", String)
        s += c != '\n' # assume Linux for simplicity
    end
    s
end
```

Now we compare the performance and memory usage of the given options:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime f1()
  239.857 ms (2001558 allocations: 146.59 MiB)
100000000

julia> @btime f2()
  179.480 ms (2001539 allocations: 137.59 MiB)
100000000

julia> @btime f3()
  189.643 ms (2001533 allocations: 137.59 MiB)
100000000

julia> @btime f4()
  158.055 ms (13 allocations: 96.32 MiB)
100000000
```

If you run it on your machine you should get similar results.